# click twice on checkbox to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, onclick, onchange

I am mapping through this array

```
array=[
    {'id': 1, 'isActive': true, 'name': apple}, 
    {'id': 2, 'isActive': false, 'name': orange}, 
    {'id': 3, 'isActive': false, 'name': forest}
]
```

I have an input that looks like this after the map of array

```
<input
    id={item.id}
    type="checkbox"
    onClick={() => handleActive(item)}
    checked={item.isActiveMarket}
/>
```

I want to change isActive inside the item when i click on the checkbox to activate or desactivate, but the array should stay full without deleting any element

For the function this is what I got

```
const handleActive = (item) => {
    item.isActive = !item.isActive;
};
```

it works but only when I double click on it

Comment: You are setting the value to an object manually. Use `useState` if its a functional component of `state` if its a class base component and update the state properly.

Comment: yes that's what i asked, i couldn't use useState to change only that element in the array

Answer (score 1):

Try to use onChange instead of onClick

Comment: the problem is i am trying to update the state manually, i need to use useState to update the element in the array

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
<input
    id={item.id}
    type="checkbox"
    onChange={() => handleActive(item)}
    checked={item.isActiveMarket}
/>
```

Comment: the problem is not with onClick

Answer (score 0):

```
const initialState = [
    {'id': 1, 'isActive': true, 'name': apple}, 
    {'id': 2, 'isActive': false, 'name': orange}, 
    {'id': 3, 'isActive': false, 'name': forest}
];

const [items, setItems] = useState(initialState);

const onActiveToggle = (id) => {
    const item = items.find(item => item.id === id);

    setItems(prev => prev.splice(prev.indexOf(item), 1, {...item, isActive: !item.isActive}));
}

...
...
<>
  {items.map((item, index) => (
    <input
    key={item.id}
    id={item.id}
    type="checkbox"
    onChange={() => handleActive(item.id)}
    checked={item.isActive}
/>
  ))}
</>

...
...
```

Comment: i already have an useState for array with const [array, setArray] = useState([]);  then i filled the array before the map after that i got the problem with the checkbox, Should i do the same thing and change setItems and items to array and setArray ?

Comment: @mykolna ASTEMA , this is the response i got 
    {'id': 3, 'isActive': false, 'name': forest}   , it removed the others from the array and left only the one i clicked on

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in a `useEffect` to update the state:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('items useEffect runs')

  }, [items])
```